# 'Chain Of Patterns' design pattern and it's potentials

Tags: design-patterns, metrics, software-design

I was searching on design-patterns and their related topics and papers in academic journals and conferences, meanwhile I found [this article](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v21/v21-32.pdf) which was about "Chains Of Design Patterns", I didn't heard anything about this topic before and after reading the paper, it didn't make any sense to me, probably because it's a brand new idea to me.

Can anyone give me some hints about this subject, is that really a 'benchmarkable' subject ? isn't choosing a proper pattern or in this case, chain of patterns, coupled to context of the problem ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the link is now dead.  Unfortunately, insufficient context now remains to know what this question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper just explains that some Design Patterns used in conjunctions (hence the term *Chain*) to implement a particular piece of code, might favor good code properties like Modularity or Learnability.

I understand how appealing are Design Patterns, first introduced in 1994 by the Gang of Four (Gof). It is a good thing for the community that DP are so widely learnt and adopted. However don't take for granted, everything concerning DP, including this academic paper.

For example the Singleton DP always leads to poor designed and untestable code, and the community banished it a long time ago (while for beginners, singleton sounds very elegant, since it is the easier DP to master). Btw, this paper refers Singleton as highly Scalable, while singleton clearly kills Scalability!

Only experience (and especially failures), will give you intuition about when to use and not to use DPs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm kind of familiar with DPs but the thing is comparing different chain of DPs (with different use cases) seems a bit nonsense (correct me if I got it wrong). for instance comparing a chain like `iterator->visitor` to  another chain like `iterator->memento`, while each of those has a different use case seems a little bit odd, if they can't be replaced with each other then what's the point of comparing them ?

Comment: I agree with you, I guess the point is that someone somewhere had to write an academic paper and DPs sound like a trendy topic.